# php sort cells in column from 1 to unlimited in table

Tags: php, sorting, numbers, position

i have table with php code like this

```
name    points

jeme      19
yoka      15
zinga     13
```

please do it by php code and also no i will give you my code to edit

```html
<?php 

// make connecion
mysql_connect('localhost', 'db user', '');

// Select Database
mysql_select_db ('db name');


$sql="SELECT sum(points) as sumpoints , name FROM wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist group by name order by sumpoints DESC";

$records=mysql_query($sql);




?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>الاحصائيات النهائية لمسابقة اكتوبر</title>
</head>

<body>

<table class="wpProQuiz_toplistTable">
    
   <tr>
   
    <th style="">Name</th>
    <th style="width: 60px;">Points</th>
   <tr>
<?php 

 while($wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
  
  echo "<tr>"; 
  
 
  
  echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[name]."</td>";
  
  echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[sumpoints]."</td>";
  
  echo "</tr>"; 
  
  
  }// End While

?>               
           
                  
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

every thing is ok with this table and i ordered names by name who win more points as you see but i still want another column and i will call it [position] and shourcut for it pos. , cause i want to rank user by this way ( numbers 1-2-3-4 ) like this

```
pos.     name      points

 1       jeme         19
 2       yoka         15
 3       zinga        13
```

Comment: The HTML portions of your code are irrelevant. What's relevant is how you are storing your data in PHP. Is it several arrays? A single associative array or ordered array containing objects? Show us that and delete all the irrelevant code about HTML above.

Comment: thank you for helping , but now everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a column for the position in html. 
And then, when you parse your sorted data, you can increment a variable like this :

```
$i=1;
while($wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$i++."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[name]."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[sumpoints]."</td>";
         echo "</tr>"; 
}// End While
```